# JSP date default value

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

What is the return type of this jsp statement if left empty?

`<td><input type="date" name="dod" value="<c:out value='${param.dod}'/>"/></td>`

I need to check if user chose to set it!

Answer (score 0):

"" (empty String object) is returned.